# How to delete "selected" attribute from option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp

I want to remove the "selected" attribute from an option element when I uncheck this. I dont want to make value false or anything... I just want to delete this property. My code is like

```
$(function() {
  $("#deployselect").multiselect({
    click: function( event, ui ) {
      if(ui.checked==false){
        $("#deployselect option[value='"+ui.value+"']").removeAttr("selected");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

My generated HTML is like this

```
<option value="68" selected>A1</option>
<option value="49" selected>A2</option>
<option value="69" selected>A3</option>
```

so even i make "attr" or "prop" false it is not working. :(

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by removing that attribute?  `selected` is a boolean _property_ whose _initial_ value is set based on the HTML attribute.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to de-select it, change this line:

```
$("#deployselect option[value='"+ui.value+"']").removeAttr("selected");
```

to

```
$("#deployselect option[value='"+ui.value+"']").prop("selected", false);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ahatez/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ahatez/1/edit)

(Assuming jQuery 1.6 or later; for earlier versions, change `prop` to `attr`.)

Once the HTML has been parsed into the DOM, the [`option` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70901257) has [a property called `selected`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70874476) which gets its initial value from the `selected` attribute in the HTML (defaulting to `false`). So once you're dealing with DOM elements, you're dealing with a boolean property, not an attribute anymore.

Comment: @Born2Lead: It works on Chrome for me, added example to the answer.

Comment: @Born2Lead: Good deal, glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to set selector value to empty so all checked list will uncheck

```
$("#deployselect").val([]);
```